# In veins 5.0, no BaseWaveApplayer class any more?

Tags: veins

I only find DemoBaseAppLayer in the project, but BaseWaveAppLayer in the veins 5.0 framework. It is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Correct - it was renamed; see https://veins.car2x.org/documentation/upgrading/